# Connect Docker Container to outside host

Tags: docker

I've a container with docker that creates a JMS Connection with an outside host ( amqp://WKSAXIPMI512:5672), it's the name of my localhost. When runnning the application outside of docker i got no error when creating the JMS Connection, when running from docker then i got the error:

```
C:\repository\tk\src\middleware\ub2b\ub2b-proto>docker run -p 8080:8080 -h=%ComputerName% proto
2018-04-03 10:04:06,256 INFO  [net.axisdata.ub2b.core.configuration.ConfigurationModule]: Configured hibernate bundle
ERROR [2018-04-03 10:04:06,574] org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnection: Failed to connect to remote at: amqp://WKSAXIPMI512:5672
2018-04-03 10:04:06,582 ERROR [net.axisdata.ub2b.core.configuration.jms.JmsConfigurationHelper]: Error configuring jms connection
javax.jms.JMSException: syscall:getsockopt(..) failed: Connection refused: WKSAXIPMI512/172.17.0.3:5672
        at org.apache.qpid.jms.exceptions.JmsExceptionSupport.create(JmsExceptionSupport.java:86)
        at org.apache.qpid.jms.exceptions.JmsExceptionSupport.create(JmsExceptionSupport.java:108)
        at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnection.connect(JmsConnection.java:168)
```

How can i connect to a outside host from a docker container ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error is in running the container with -h=%ComputerName% as my computer name is WKSAXIPMI512. So when inside the container i'm pointing to WKSAXIPMI512 is pointing to the container itself.

When running without -h=%ComputerName% there is no problem